# Why using user input as format control causes security breach?

Tags: java

In java, it is possible to use `printf` as follows:

```
System.out.printf("User name is:%n%s%n", user.getName());
```

It is discouraged to use input from user for format-control string (i.e., `"User name is:%n%s%n"`). While I can see this is a bad idea to do so, I cannot find a concrete example when this causes a security issue. I was wondering if someone can give an example in which this bad programming practices causes a security breach.

Comment: Can you cite a source for your *assertion*?

Comment: Who ever said it is a security issue in Java? In C it might be, but not in Java.

Comment: I read it in "Java How to Program" 10th edition (Page 76). @ElliottFrisch
[link]http://www.deitel.com/Books/Java/JavaHowtoProgram10eEarlyObjects/tabid/3656/Default.aspx